# Can we change the view for AG grid in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, ag-grid

I have been working on ag grid since quite long time. Currently we got a requirement to change the grid display for mobile devices (for example width <480 px).

Does Ag grid support/convert its view for small devices? If yes, could you provide the relevant link for the same?

Comment: Interesting point is that the table on their landing page adjusts itself quite nice on mobile (less columns), but they don't provide any guides on this topic..

Answer (score 8):

AgGrid adjust by itself. The default themes is capable of dynamic resizing itself.

You can use `params.api.sizeColumnsToFit()` in either on `onGridReady` or `onFirstDataRendered`. This will do dynamic resizing with scrolls.

However i would suggest to create a seperate view for mobile, display only relevant colums which makes sense in mobile view.

```
var column = [{ field: "Col1" }, { field: "Col2", }, { field: "Col3", }, { field: "Col4", }, { field: "Col5", }];

    var mobileColumn = [{ field: "Col1" }, { field: "Col2", }, { field: "Col3", }];

    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (window.innerWidth <= 480) {
                gridOptions.setColumnDefs(mobileColumn);
                params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            }
        })
    })
```

dynamically set columns for mobile view

Comment: Can we combine multiple cells into one that has a list like display eg: td1 td2 td3 to be like td with ul li items inside